# Finding closest coordinates (Long, Lat) efficiently in python

Tags: algorithm, sorting, pyspark, location, geo

I have a pyspark dataframe of points that represent a certain location in the United States in the form of street address, city, state, zipcode, longitude and latitude.

I want to, for each point, get the closest point out of this dataframe (not including the point in question, obviously).

What would be the most efficient way to do that?

The data set I am using has around 5 million different locations.

Comment: The first thing that comes to mind is a quadtree. But first you have to say how many points you have? If you have n points, bruteforcing the problem takes n^2 operations, which might or might not be okay.

Comment: try hnsw, very fast, you dont need distributed, if not use geo-hashing, also very fast.

Comment: @E.ZY.how would I use geohashing? Can you give me an example?